# Linux find-command skips a directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

I have certain network share folders mounted in the `/media` directory.

I want to make sure that when I do something like `sudo find / -name foo` it should always skip the `/media` directory.

I don't want to pass a parameter to the `find` command ... I want to configure my system in such a way that `find` always by default skips `/media` directory.

Comment: You want to use `find / -xdev -name foo`, not sure what you mean *don't want to pass a parameter to the find*

Comment: let's say you pass a parameter to find and make it skip the directory. you need to remember and pass that parameter every time. I want to put it in a place that I can use the find command normally and it still skips the unwanted directories.

Comment: I think you can't. With program that use configuration file, you can instruct it by setting some thing in configuration file. `find` and other standard tools didn't.

Comment: Using various command-line options to `find` to refine the search to exactly what you want **is** using the find command "normally".  You can't use an alias for this, either as the first arg(s) need to be the search dir(s).  Even writing a function would be extremely difficult, if not impossible, for the same reason...and because some `find` options need to come before any others.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of edge cases that need to be considered in this situation. The first approach, `find / -path '/media' -prune -o ...` is sufficient only when the search path is absolute and begins with `/`. The scenario `cd / && find * ...` will never match the `-path '/media'` clause.

Fortunately the `-inum` parameter can come to the rescue. Inode numbers are unique only per mounted filesystem, so in order to exclude `/media` we need to identify the tuple consisting of the filesystem and the inode number.

The following (long) script will exclude `/media` for you, hopefully catching enough of the edge cases to be useful.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#
FIND=/usr/bin/find


# Process prefix arguments
#
opt_H= opt_L= opt_P= opt_D= opt_O=
while getopts 'HLPD:O:' opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        H)      opt_H=-H ;;
        L)      opt_L=-L ;;
        P)      opt_P=-P ;;
        D)      opt_D="-D $OPTARG" ;;
        O)      opt_O="-O $OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))


# Find the inode number for /media and its filesystem
#
m_inode=$(stat -c '%i' /media 2>/dev/null)
m_fsys=$(stat -c '%m' /media 2>/dev/null)


# Collect the one or more filesystem roots to search
#
roots=()
while [[ 0 -lt $# && "$1" != -* ]]
do
    roots+=("$1")
    shift
done


# Collect the "find" qualifiers. Some of them need to be at the front
# of the list. Unfortunately.
#
pre_args=() args=()
while [[ 0 -lt $# ]]
do
    # We really ought to list all qualifiers here, but I got tired of
    # typing for an example
    #
    case "$1" in
        -maxdepth)      pre_args+=("$1"); pre_args+=("$2"); shift 2 ;;
        -mindepth)      pre_args+=("$1"); pre_args+=("$2"); shift 2 ;;
        -mount|-xdev)   pre_args+=("$1"); shift ;;
        -depth|-d)      pre_args+=("$1"); shift ;;
        -name|-iname)   args+=("$1"); args+=("$2"); shift 2 ;;
        -path|-ipath)   args+=("$1"); args+=("$2"); shift 2 ;;
        *)              args+=("$1") ; shift ;;
    esac
done
test -z "${args[*]}" && args=('-print')


# Iterate across the collected filesystem roots, attempting to skip
# /media only if the filesystem matches
#
exit_ss=0
for root in "${roots[@]}"
do
    fsys=$(stat -c '%m' "$root" 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ -n "$m_inode" && -n "$m_fsys" && "$fsys" == "$m_fsys" ]]
    then
        # Same filesystem. Exclude /media by inode
        #
        "$FIND" ${opt_H:+"$opt_H"} ${opt_L:+"$opt_L"} \
                ${opt_P:+"$opt_P"} ${opt_O:+"$opt_O"} \
                ${opt_O:+"$opt_O"} "$root" "${pre_args[@]}" \
                \( -inum "$m_inode" -prune \) -o \( "${args[@]}" \)
        ss=$?
        [[ 0 -lt $ss ]] && exit_ss="$ss"
    else
        # Different filesystem so we don't need to worry about /media
        #
        "$FIND" ${opt_H:+"$opt_H"} ${opt_L:+"$opt_L"} \
                ${opt_P:+"$opt_P"} ${opt_O:+"$opt_O"} \
                ${opt_O:+"$opt_O"} "$root" "${pre_args[@]}" \
                "${pre_args[@]}" \( "${args[@]}" \)
        ss=$?
        [[ 0 -lt $ss ]] && exit_ss="$ss"
    fi
done


# All done
#
exit $exit_ss
```

Comment: @mikeserv I've left unquoted the items that should disappear if unset, but be parsed by the shell otherwise. I tested enough of it to be happy the principle was valid. Thank you for the typo spot. Please feel free to throw your other fixes into the mix.

Comment: @mikeserv thank you for updates. I was aware of `${var:+$othervar}` but I hadn't realised one could double-quote the substitution. Nice to learn something new. Empty parentheses fixed.

Comment: the quoting actually breaks `-D` unless its arg is passed concatenated now, though. it is perhaps safer, but maybe also less useful. its kind of what i meant before about `eval` - unless youre really prepared to actually handle everything in lieu of the wrapped program, the safest, most simple way to intrude only a little bit is to touch as lightly as possible. thats why i just did `find "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"` and etc - i'd rather all/any errors be handled by `find` than have to do it myself. i guess it really breaks `-D` since now there are two `-O`s. was that my fault? sorry if so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to "simple" usage of `find` (i.e. not multiple dirs, no options `-H -L -D -P -O`) and are OK with using the `-xdev` option, try this simple answer. This will exclude all mounted filesystem (e.g. also `$HOME` if it is separately mounted).

You may define a bash function `find` such that it doesn't decent into other file systems.
Put this in your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you are using `bash`)

```
find () {
  local path="${1}"
  shift
  command find "${path}" -xdev "${@}"
}
```

Explanation: We need to use a function instead of an alias because `find` is very picky about the ordering of its arguments. The `path` must be the first argument. Therefore, we save the `path` in a local variable and pop it from the argument list (`shift`). Then we run the original find `command find` with the path and all remaining arguments `$@`. The `command` in front of `find` makes sure we do not end up with a recursive call.

With the new `~/.bashrc` file, you need to source it first

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, you may use the new version of `find`. You can always check the definition using

```
> type find
find is a function
find ()
{
    local path="${1}";
    shift;
    command find "${path}" -xdev "${@}"
}
```

Comment: There can be more than one path.  Try something like `local -a paths ; while [ -d "$1" ] ; do paths+=("$1") ; shift ; done` and later `find "$paths[@]" ...`

Comment: yes, this solution is not bullet proof. Also, there are "real options" to `find` which precede the path (`-H -L -D -P -O`), which one would need to take into account if aim is 100% compatibility. I'm leaving these exotic cases as an exercise to the reader. Edits welcome. Cheers.

Comment: It also doesn't do quite what the OP asked for.  `-xdev` stops `find` from descending into other mounted filesystems, while the OP asked to exclude `/media`.  `/media` almost always is a directory containing several mounted filesystem on modern linux distros....but a) this will exclude /boot, /usr, /home, /var etc if they happen to be separate mounts, and b) doesn't work if /media isn't a mount-point or if there's a need to exclude another directory that isn't.   Unfortunately, the obvious solution involving `-path /media -prune` can't come before certain other options like `maxdepth`.

Comment: I see you've thought about this much more thoroughly than I have. Thanks for providing feedback to my answer. Much appreciated! I now agree that a more complex solution is required to cover the needs of OP exactely.

Comment: It's why i said even a function is difficult if not impossible.  You'd have to write a full-featured option pre-processor that handled every find option and test and arg to make sure it worked correctly in all cases.  and something that only works sometimes is broken.

Comment: btw, the while loop i suggested above is also broken.  i can easily think of several situations where it will break.  it would have to be much more complicated to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
(   set -e -- "$(command -v find)"
    [ -x "${1:?}"  ]
    [ ! -e "$1cmd" ]
    [ ! -L "$1cmd" ]
    mv -- "$1"  "$1cmd"
    cat > "$1"
    chmod +x -- "$1"
)   <<""
#!/bin/sh -f
eval '  exec    "$0cmd" '"${1$(                       # f!'"ing colors
        unset   i L O M rt IFS
        chk()   case   ${O+$2}${2--}    in            # $O must be set or $2
                (-maxdepth"$2") M=      ;;            # unset to match "$2$2"
                ([\(!]"$2"|-*"$2")                    # this is the last match
                        printf  %s${1+%b}%.d\
                               "$rt" \\c 2>&-   &&    # printf fails if ! $1  
                        chk(){  ${1+:} exit; }  ;;    # chk() = !!$1 || exit
                (-?*)   shift   $((OPTIND=1))         # handle -[HLP] for 
                        while   getopts :HLP    O     # path resolution w/
                        do      case    $O${L=} in    # NU$L expansions
                                (P)     unset L ;;    # $[HL]=:- $P=-
                                (\?)    rt= chk ''    # opt unexpected  &&
                                        return  ;;    # abandon parse
                        esac;   done;   unset O ;;    # $O is unset until 
                (${M-${O=?*}})                        # above matches fail
                      ! [ ! -L "${L-$2}" ]      ||    # ! -P ||!! -L ||
                        [ !  / -ef "$2"  ]      ||    # !  / == $2   ||
                        rt=$rt' ! \( -path "${'$i'%/}/media/*" -prune \)'
                esac
        while   chk ${1+$((i+=1)) "$1"}               # loop while args remain
        do      printf ' "${'$i}\"                    # printf args to eval
                shift                                 # shift args away
        done                                          # done
)"
```

There's a wrapper script for `find` that will insert a few arguments to forbid the real `find` from looking in `/media/` if any of its path arguments equal `/`.

There are two portions of the above script: there's the actual script *(which is everything following `<<""\n`*) and there's the run-once installation bit at the top *(which is everything between the first matched-pair of `(` parentheses `)`)*.

#### install

```sh
(   set -e -- "$(command -v find)"         #get /path/to/find
    [ -x "${1:?}"  ]                       #else loudly fail
    [ ! -e "$1cmd" ]                       #fail if /path/to/findcmd
    [ ! -L "$1cmd" ]                       #and double-check
    mv -- "$1"  "$1cmd"                    #rename .../find -> .../findcmd
    cat > "$1"                             #copy stdin to .../find
    chmod +x -- "$1"                       #set new find's executable bit
)   <<"" ###stdin
```

The installation bit takes a little care *not* to complete successfully unless there's a reasonable chance it can do so without directly modifying anything on your system but your `$PATH`'d `find` executable's filename - it wants to change that from `/path/to/find` to `/path/to/findcmd` and will make the attempt if `/path/to/findcmd` doesn't already exist. If its tests prove true - and if you have appropriate permissions for applying the commands at all - it will rename the `find` executable and install a new shell script named `find` in its place.

The installed script will forever thereafter rely on the renamed `findcmd` executable remaining where it left it *(so you'll likely want to inform your package-manager of this if you use one)* and each time it is invoked it will replace itself with `$0cmd` called with all its arguments after it has had a peek at them. If you don't do whatever is necessary to make the installation permanent, then eventually most  package-managers will wind up overwriting the installed script with a newly updated `find` binary at some point, and so you'll be right back where you started except that you'll also have an older `find` named `findcmd` in the system's `../bin` directory.

Given appropriate permissions and that your system doesn't warrant any undue surprises, the entire script should be self-installable with a copy-paste into a shell-prompt *(though you'll need to do an extra RETURN at the end)*. If it doesn't work that way, then, at the least, there ought to be no harm done in the attempt anyway.

#### newfind

```sh
#!/bin/sh -f
eval '  exec    "$0cmd" '"${1+$(                      # f!'"ing colors
        unset   i L O M rt IFS
        chk()   case   ${O+$2}${2--}    in            # $O must be set or $2
                (-maxdepth"$2") M=      ;;            # unset to match "$2$2"
                ([\(!]"$2"|-*"$2")                    # this is the last match
                        printf  %s${1+%b}%.d\
                               "$rt" \\c 2>&-   &&    # printf fails if ! $1  
                        chk(){  ${1+:} exit; }  ;;    # chk() = !!$1 || exit
                (-?*)   shift   $((OPTIND=1))         # handle -[HLP] for 
                        while   getopts :HLP    O     # path resolution w/
                        do      case    $O${L=} in    # NU$L expansions
                                (P)     unset L ;;    # $[HL]=:- $P=-
                                (\?)    rt= chk ''    # opt unexpected  &&
                                        return  ;;    # abandon parse
                        esac;   done;   unset O ;;    # $O is unset until 
                (${M-${O=?*}})                        # above matches fail
                      ! [ ! -L "${L-$2}" ]      ||    # ! -P ||!! -L ||
                        [ !  / -ef "$2"  ]      ||    # !  / == $2   ||
                        rt=$rt' ! \( -path "${'$i'%/}/media/*" -prune \)'
                esac
        while   chk ${1+$((i+=1)) "$1"}               # loop while args remain
        do      printf ' "${'$i}\"                    # printf args to eval
                shift                                 # shift args away
        done                                          # done
)}"
```

My first and foremost rule when writing a wrapper script is: ***hands-off***. If I needed a program I'd try to write one, but since I've already got a program worth wrapping, I'll try to let it do what it already does unimpeded and to modify as little as possible about its behavior to achieve my end-goal. This means I shouldn't do anything that might affect its execution environment in any way that doesn't directly relate to the purpose of the wrap. So I don't set variables, I don't interpret arguments, I don't touch i/o streams, and I don't alter the wrapped program's process group or its parent pid. In all things the wrapper should be as transient and as transparent as possible.

The above script achieves this goal, moreso now than before. I wasn't  satisfied before - especially regarding path resolutions - but I believe I have addressed that. In order to do so properly I had to track `[HLP]` state so that I could correctly compare symbolic links against `/` when either of `-H` or `-L` options were effective and `-P` did not negate them. If the link test passes the current argument is checked for an `-ef` equal file inode match to `/` - which means practically any name for `/` will work *(to include symlinks when `-H` or `-L` are effective)*. So I feel better about that stuff, and I've set it up to block `/proc` and `/sys` and `/dev` from `/` searches by default.

What it does especially well is avoid modifying any of its called state before passing that on to `$0cmd`. It pointedly declines to interpret an argument set which includes any option which it is not prepared to handle and in those cases passes the entire set along to `$0cmd` untouched, and so, while in those cases it may not block the path search, neither does it affect `find`'s behavior in any other way. It is for this reason that the `eval "exec wrapped_program $(arg-handler)"` method is the one I favor most for these sorts of things.

***top-level***

In fact, as indicated above, at its top-level the entire shell-script amounts only to the single simple command - which tells it to replace itself with another executable. Any work done at all is done within the `$(` command substitution `)` subshell, and all of its state - modified or not - is fully localized. The purpose behind `eval` at all is to get a second look at the script's arguments without needing actually to affect them unnecessarily - and that's what this wrapper is all about.

When the `$(` command sub `)` has done its job the resulting `exec`'d command will be either:

```
exec "$0cmd" "${1}" ... ! \( -path "${[num]%/}/media/*" -prune \) "${2}" ...
```

...where all of the original arguments - if any - are referenced in order and by number in their original and unaltered form *(even null arguments)* in addition to the the six *(`!`, `\(`, `-path`, `"${[num]%/}/media/*"`, `-prune`, `\)`)* insertions a set of which occurs for each successful `/ -ef "${num}"` test during the arg scan. Otherwise it will be simply:

```
exec "$0cmd" "${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}" ...
```

...where all of the original arguments are referenced in the very same way with no insertions at all.

So the only two possible modifications this wrapper can make to the environment of its wrapped target are these:

- It alters the process name from its own to its name + *`cmd`*. This always happens.
- It may inject six arguments per root match into the list of those with which it was called.

So long as the first alteration is given as acceptable *(though it is avoidable)*, there is a single point of failure here regarding behavior modification - and that is whether or not the argument insertion is valid. Any errors otherwise associated with invocation are simply out-of-scope and should be handled by the wrap target, and this wrapper tries to mind its business.

***arg-handler***

Within the command substitution I first init vars to unset because the `""` string is the best way to *not* match a path when needed. I then declare the `chk()` function, and afterward call it for each iteration of the `while` loop which will increment `$i` by one for each of the script's invocation arguments. It will print each increment `$i` wrapped in quotes and braces preceded by a space and a dollar sign to the command sub's stdout:

```
printf ' "${'$i}\"
```

...

```
 "${1}"
```

It loops over calls to `chk()` which gets a copy of its arguments per iteration, then `shift`s it away until none remain and the loop completes. `chk()` compares its argument to its patterns and takes the appropriate actions:

- `(-maxdepth"$2") M= ;;`

  - When `$M` is set the last pattern can only match a null string which can only fail its block's subsequent path comparison tests, and so *`rt=$rt+!\(`* and so on never occurs in that case. Otherwise nothing is done.
  - The POSIX spec only requires `-[HL]` to be recognized before any `[...path...]` operands, and any others are unspecified. Here's what it says about which are `[...path...]` operands and which are test operands:

    > The first operand and subsequent operands up to but not including the first operand that starts with a `−`, or is a `!`  or a `(`, shall be interpreted as `[...path...]` operands. If the first operand starts with a `−`, or is a `!`  or a `(`, the behavior is unspecified. Each path operand is a pathname of a starting point in the file hierarchy.
- `([\(!]"$2"|-*"$2")`

  - The current argument is a single `(`left-paren, or a `!`bang, or it begins with a `-*`dash but is not `-maxdepth` and the last pattern has been matched at least one time.
  - `printf %s ${1+%b}%.d "$rt" \\c 2>&- &&`

    - Write the value of `$rt` - if any - to the command substitution's standard out followed by a successful zero-length write of the `\c` `%b` escape, or a failed conversion to `%.d`ecimal of same and with the same length if `$1` is not set and the end of arguments has been reached. This failure will end the `while` loop.
  - `chk(){ ${1+:} exit; }`

    - If `printf` is successful then `chk()` has made its one and only attempt to modify any arguments at all. From this point on the `while` loop may continue to handle and print the rest of the args, but `chk()` won't do anything at all until all of these are exhausted at which point it will just `exit` the subshell. And so once the second pattern matches even once, none of the others ever match again.
- `(-?*)`

  - The current argument is at least two characters and begins with a dash. This pattern is *more* exclusive than the `-*"$2"` pattern above it once `$O` is set and so it can only ever match until at least a single argument *doesn't* match it. In this way all initial options will be split out with `getopts` and matched against `[HPL]`. If any initial option doesn't fit that pattern the function calls itself recursively to match the pattern above it and redefine `chk()`. In this way any arg sequence which is not explicitly handled is merely passed through verbatim and `findcmd` does whatever it will with the results.
  - For each initial option which matches `-[HL]` the flag variable `$L` is set to the null string. And for each of those that match `-P` `$L` is `unset`.
- `(${M-${O=?*}})`

  - The first occurring argument which doesn't match `-?*` will trigger `$O`'s being set to the `?*` pattern. Thereafter any of the first two patterns can match `${O+$2}${2--}`. If ever `-maxdepth$2` is matched and `M=` is set to the null string, this pattern can never again match another not-null argument, and only a single match of the second pattern is required to cease all attempts at matching any of them.
  - Any not-null argument which occurs after the first sequence of `-[HLP]` options and before another `-*` or `[\(?!]` argument matches this pattern and is tested for path resolution. If `$L` is unset then the `! ! -L "${L-$2}"` test will pass if `$2` is a symbolic link or invalid pathname, but otherwise invariably fails because no pathname can match the `${L=}` nullstring.
  - Only those arguments which fail the previous test are checked for a `!` negated inode match to `/` and any argument which fails both tests results in `$rt` being set to itself plus the `! \( -path "${[num]%/}/media/* -prune \)` string which is not written until the second pattern matches or the end of arguments is reached, whichever comes first.

Comment: how does this cope with multiple paths, or with options like `-maxdepth` which have to come before most other options?  or `-H`, `-L` which have to come before the path?  works OK?

Comment: @cas - it copes with multiple paths fine, but i didnt do anything for `-[HL]`. basically it will search the initial arguments until it finds a `!` or a `-*`. if before any of those it also finds a `/` then it will insert `! -path '/media/*'` and immediately afterward redefine the `chk()` function to a no-op. are those the only three types that need to come first? i could handle those with two additional `case` patterns, but im not really looking to write a whole program. the `eval` bit is totally safe though - all the subshell does besides insert that one `-path` thing is write `"${1}" "${2}"`

Comment: @cas - i think that should do it.

Comment: nice.  probably should handle everything before [path] in `find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: btw, `-maxdepth` doesn't have to come before the path like `-H`, `-L`, etc.  It should come immediately after it, otherwise find will whinge about it affecting all tests not just those that come after.  `-maxdepth` also takes an arg.  there are a few others that do the same thing.

Comment: @cas i dunno what all that stuff is, but the spec says `find` can only accept `-[HL]` before `[path...]`. if the asker wants to stick a test in for extensions he/she is more than welcome, and the how is fairly obvious.

Comment: @cas - the `-maxdepth` stuff is fine. it still works that way - as long as it comes before any `-*` or `!` argument that isnt `-[HL]` theres no problem - and if its arg is either of those its a syntax error anyway.

Comment: yep, you're right.  posix only supports -H and -L.  What I pasted was from GNU find.  freebsd is `find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]`

Comment: @cas - dang. thats a lot of stuff. its just a longer `case` statement, but im not terribly interested in writing it. you were right about `\(` expression though - i forgot to handle the parens.

Comment: yeah it's why i said it would be difficult or impossible.  it's not difficult to come up with a semi-working solution.  very hard to do it so that it actually works in all situations.

Comment: @cas - well, not hard, just tedious. i wrote a 60-line wrapper for `dd` and it took a couple hours, but i use it every day, and its bullet-proof. and once you write it once it saves you a lot of time. i do `_dd - + i1k o2k c1bx1b Sbe iflag=sync` for `dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/fd/1 ibs=1k obs=2k cbs=1bx1b conv=swab,block,noerror iflag=sync`

Comment: mikeserv, @cas, "_**BUGS**: The syntax is painful._" --from the `find` manpage, Unix v7.  _And it's been all down hill from there!_